# Hardening Captcha security

Tags: security, session-variables, captcha

Nearly all websites use CAPTCHA images to protect their forms from spam. But is this the most secure way? As far as i understand, the idea of CAPTCHA is to challenge the user with an image containing some "hard-to-recognize" text so that if the visitor is a human being (not a bot) he/she will be able to post data but not machines. The website sends the captcha code (image) and a session variable containing perhaps a hashed version of the captcha image (the correct answer but hashed). The user submits the form and the server has to make sure that the hash of the letters he/she typed = the hash contained in the session variable. 
Fine, what if i (the spammer) wrote a piece of software that mimics that same request and sends it to the server? in other words, if the captcha is abc123 and the hash (in the session variable which can be read with any HTTP sniffer) is xyz345 (consider this a 32 character string) and i sent this data to the server in a post request? Then i start to be more creative, i put this code in a 10,000 loop that will overwhelm the server with spam data! Now is CAPTCHA that secure? are their any options by which i can face such a threat?
Thanks

Comment: am sorry but as far as i understand Session is a server side entity and its not transported to client by any means, i couldn't understand the concept of Sniffing session variables , could you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Sessions are contained in the HTTP request of the user. It should be there, otherwise the server won't "recognize" the user. Don't forget that HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Comment: Sir , http is a sessionless protocol but the server doesnt send session to the client , it just sends a session identifier to the client which client returns on the next call, the session variable remain only at the server side, so there is no issue of loosing the session values

Comment: Fine, Can i resend this session_identifier over and over? yes i can and i already wrote a C# program that did this very thing. The program was able to bypass the CAPTCHA security for one of my sites and the form was used to send mails to the clients. Imagine the amount of spam that was produced.

Comment: But in that scenario , might be u missed some part where in you were allowing to send it without the Captcha, and ya if you still feel that you can , try your hands on any production running popular sites that need captach, may be something like gmail  ,try to bypass their captchas

Comment: I did send the CAPTCHA code in the POST variables, together with the session identifier. By the way the site i tried it on was a production one (not gmail of course but it was in business).

Comment: no i didnt specifically mean, but what you are saying is like u send the form without captcha and submitted , well that might be a flaw in the application. but honestly i dont forsee any chance that the user will be able to pass the captcha if thats properly implemented and captcha is used all over to avoid the programmatic users like bots and other things, though captcha can be cracked if you are able to detect the text in captcha using your programs and submit that value

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are wrong: Neither can the session data be read by the client nor are Captchas meant to mitigate DOS attacks.

A Captcha is a challenge/response technique where the server issues the client a challenge that is meant to be only solvable by a human. An optical character recognition (OCR) challenge that most of the Captchas present is just one variant but certainly a good one as OCR is easier for most literate humans but pose a problem for computers.

But any Captcha is worthless if the response to the challenge is easy to guess, to derive, or to obtain otherwise. Sending the expected response in plain or in a derived form in a hidden form field is such an example. Having the response passed to the Captcha image as a parameter is another example.

That’s why the expected response should stay at the server side, as a session datum, that is not readable by the client as only the session’s identifier is transmitted.

Your second concern, that Captchas can’t prevent DOS attacks, is true. Again, that’s not the reason Captchas were supposed to solve. Captchas were invented to “tell computers and humans apart” and nothing else. They can only help to prevent automated spamming to succeed. But frankly, intense challenge/response generation is rather likely to lead to DOS.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha is not a way to prevent stealing session cookies. If you want secure sessions use e.g. HTTPS.

Captcha does not prevent (D)DOS attacks, if you want your server to be save against 10.000 spam requests per second, put countermeasures against that.

The only purpose of a captcha is to decide whether a request comes from a human being or a machine. That shall prevent automated scripts that create accounts and such but you still have to secure your website including the security of the captcha by other means. A server that exposes the answer of a captcha or lets the user decide which captcha to solve is doing it wrong.

The ideal captcha would be trivial to solve for every human but impossible to solve for every machine. So it should not be a challenge for the user. Machines are unfortunately pretty good so you have to raise the challenge and that makes it hard for us too.

Comment: I was not talking about DDOS attacks. I was talking about attacking the purpose CAPTCHA code existed at the first place: I can send the "legitimate" request to the server that appears to be coming from a human being while it is originating from a bot that i created that will mimic a genuine request by just adding the "correct" session variable to my request. This "correct" session variable can be grabbed from any HTTP sniffer that sniffs one (only one) request from a human. The bot will re-generate this request as many times as needed to create accounts or send mails. Do you get the idea?

Comment: Not the captcha's fault if that works. If you authenticate once and can do as many requests with that session as you want then your problem is in your authentication schema. If you simply require a new captcha authenticated session for every action that can be abused you can't do anything with sniffing since your session is not valid for more than 1 action.